# Cross-browser JavaScript input live change/paste detection

Tags: javascript, jquery, input, jquery-events

Is there a **cross-browser way to detect live changes to an input field**?

By *live*, I mean not when the field loses focus, and not on the next keypress, and so on. Immediately or something like it.

Using combinations of jQuery and `.change()`, `.keyup()`, `.bind('paste')` and so on I can get working live change detection in **some browsers, but not all**. Using different combinations will make it work somewhat in other browsers.

The **trickiest thing to get working is mouse manipulation** of the input field - selecting text and moving it (which is essentially cut and paste), right-clicking and pasting or cutting, etc. For some reason even `.mousedown()` and `.mouseup()` don't seem to cut it.

The only cross-browser solution I can think of right now is to **check the input field value every 100-or-so milliseconds** and compare the value against a stored value. **But this seems like overkill** when the event-based solution comes so close.

Is there a jQuery plug-in that does this already? Or is there some other way to achieve this?

Comment: jQuery should be cross browser compatible in that regard, at least for those browsers and their version found at http://docs.jquery.com/Browser_Compatibility; If this isn't the case I would suggest you file a bug.

Comment: @aza I'm not exactly sure which jQuery event helpers to use to achieve what I want (an immediate update on any change to the value of the input field), since `.change()` is fired when the input field loses focus. Do you know?

Comment: A simple solution is described here:
http://whattheheadsaid.com/2010/09/effectively-detecting-user-input-in-javascript

Answer (score 2):

To complete your change and key handlers, you can add handlers for [cut/copy/paste](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/events/cutcopypaste.html). They work in Firefox >=3, IE, Safari and Chrome (but not in Opera/Konqueror).

Would that cover everything for your use case?

Comment: Looks promising. Doesn't detect drag-and-drop changes in IE8 though. Thanks, will investigate further. `Traditional` event attach method is `elm['onchange'] = fn`?

Comment: @javascripteroo: Good to know, that about IE8. Yes, that's the traditional model (same as elm.onchange = fn), more info here: http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_tradmod.html

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the Browsers you need to support you might use HTML5's [oninput](http://help.dottoro.com/ljhxklln.php).
It fires immediately when the monitored input changes. In jQuery you would just do:

```
$('#my-input').bind('input', function(e) {
    console.log("#my-input's value changed");
});
```

Comment: `oninput` browser support: http://blog.danielfriesen.name/2010/02/16/html5-browser-maze-oninput-support/